# Columns Sum from Database to JTextfield in Netbeans Ask

Tags: netbeans

I really also cant understand the process, i think in short term of it is adding all records from database to jframe and put it to textfield
I have 
Database named OrderedList
Jframe OrderJframe
JtextField OrderRow
JButton orderbtn

Comment: Try to keep it simple not an essay!

Comment: Sorry I really also cant understand the process, i think in short term of it is adding all records from database to jframe and put it to textfield.